# XUnit Theory-like data at the level of class, NOT method

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

1. I use XUnit to run unit tests in C# code.
2. I have many abstract unit tests classes, which take one standard extra fairly complicated parameter (in comparison to a standard XUnit test class setup).
3. The values of that parameter come from some static list (for the simplicity of the example).
4. I need to run all relevant unit test classes for all possible values of the parameter from that list and **without repetitive boilerplate code**.

In a sense this is equivalent to `TheoryData`, but applied at the level of test class rather than at the level of the method. Is this possible within current XUnit framework? If yes, then how exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a ClassData as mentioned [here](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/)

You create some kind of Generator class like below and use the ClassData fixture with Theory.

```
public class TestDataGenerator : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    private readonly List<object[]> _data = new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[] {5, 1, 3, 9},
        new object[] {7, 1, 5, 3}
    };

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator() => _data.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

public class ParameterizedTests
{
    public bool IsOddNumber(int number)
    {
        return number % 2 != 0;
    }

    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(TestDataGenerator))]
    public void AllNumbers_AreOdd_WithClassData(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(a));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(b));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(c));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I had that in mind. That requires decorating every test method of every test class with this class data attribute. This defeats DRY principle and also prohibits adding some useful theory data to some tests when needed. A solution could be to apply some custom attribute at the level of the class and then "unwind" inside the constructor of some base class to get the list of parameters and then use foreach in each test. Unfortunately that will not let xUnit recognize all such tests as different.

Comment: Agreed, I think it is just the limitations of the available tools.  I ended up doing similar to what you are saying and then added a custom logger to gather test results xunit doesn't recognize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IClassFixture. Create a customized TFixture to return data to your test class constructor.

```
namespace Xunit
{
    public interface IClassFixture<TFixture> where TFixture : class
    {
    }
}
```

And your method should inherit the customized fixture

```
public class ParameterizedTests: IClassFixture<TFixture>
{
    public ParameterizedTests(TFixture fixture)
    {
    }

    public bool IsOddNumber(int number)
    {
        return number % 2 != 0;
    }

    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(TestDataGenerator))]
    public void AllNumbers_AreOdd_WithClassData(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(a));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(b));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(c));
        Assert.True(IsOddNumber(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is TestDataGenerator defined?

Comment: Fixture just shares data between tests, what he's looking for is how to parameterize the test class, not the method