# Repeating xUnit test class with different parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm working on an application where I need to maintain 2 different versions of the same component but still need to test compatibility with another component. I really don't want to use `[Theory]` with `[InlineData(CompV1)]`, `[InlineData(CompV2)]` over each test method so I'm just wondering if there is a way to run a whole test class twice with these components being the only variable that's changed.

For example, instead of:

```
namespace TestNS 
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData(component1)]
        [InlineData(component2)]
        public void MethodToTestCompatibility(Comp c)
        {
        ... // do something with c
        }
    }
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
namespace TestNS 
{
    [RepeatThisAttribute]
    [RunWith(component1)]
    [RunWith(component2)]
    public class TestClass
    {
        private Comp c; //component1 or component2
        public void MethodToTestCompatibility()
        {
        ... // do something with c
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit? Also: You could have ClassData instead of InlineData for the Theory.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852183/xunit-theory-like-data-at-the-level-of-class-not-method) answer your question?

Comment: @Fildor The thing I want to avoid is creating this dependency, that, if I or any of my colleagues want to test this component, they must remember to include the Theory and Inline/Class/any-Data attributes. Not to mention, if in the future we'll have to maintain 3+ versions of the aforementioned component, the problem itself will get much greater. This solution would solve it, having to add only 1 line of code for anything new. But if it's not possible, I think we might need to restructure some stuff, haha

Comment: I don't see much of a difference, there, honestly.